# Upload images to Azure blob storage don't support format error

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

After upload images to azure blob the images look like https://dodealstorge.blob.core.windows.net/upload/2021-03-31/20210331T071342445.jpg is not uploading the right img ,I changed container access level to public in Azure portal

this is the code:

```
        private async Task<string> UploadFileToBlobAsync(string strFileName,  byte[] fileData, string fileMimeType)
    {
        
            if (fileName != null && fileData != null)
            {
                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);                  
                cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = fileMimeType;                  
                await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                return cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            }
            return "";
        }
       
    }
```

Controller :

```
 var fileName = Path.GetFileName(photoIform.FileName);
                            var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, photoIform.FileName), FileMode.Create);
                            string mimeType = photoIform.ContentType;
                            byte[] fileData = new byte[photoIform.Length];
                             // Update
                            photoIform.OpenReadStream(); 
                            BlobStorageService objBlobService = new BlobStorageService();
                            img2.ImgPath = objBlobService.UploadFileToBlob(photoIform.FileName, fileData, mimeType);
```

Comment: you aren't reading in the file data before calling `UploadFileToBlob`. You are allocating the array (`byte[] fileData = new byte[photoIform.Length];`) then just uploading it.

Comment: I update the code and add  photoIform.OpenReadStream(); but still the same

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: I still have the issue, any solution ?